# Android NETWORK_PROVIDER location

Tags: android, networking, location

I'm having little problem with getting my current location using NETWORK_PROVIDDER.

My code looks like this:

```
LocationManager lMgr = (LocationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean isNetworkProviderEnabled = lMgr
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Location location = lMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (location != null) {
    // deal somehow with last (very likely outdated location)
}

if (isNetworkProviderEnabled) {
    lMgr.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Of course I have MyLocationListener that deals with location changes and **ALL REQUIRED PERMISSIONS ARE ADDED TO MANIFEST**

And the problem is that on some phones this code works like charm, but one others, the "requestLocationUpdates" does totally nothing. Of course on those problematic phones, when I open Google Maps application, my **current** location appears immediately. So my question is (I believe that people from Google should answer this): how this is done that Google Maps retrieves current location immediately, and other apps don't? Is my code wrong? Of course I have seen code like this in many stackoverflow questions. If anyone wish to know, this kind of problem appears on some Samsung Galaxy Nexus S phones

In my application GPS is not used to save battery power, but location services are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently faced the same issue, LocationManager is buggy and not implemented completely on Samsung phones. They also consume a lot of power. Use `LocationClient` to solve both these issues. `LocationClient` uses all means available to get you the last location, so its the super set of all your providers and sensors.

I faced issues with the Samsung Y model phones, I wonder which phones you are talking about. To fix the problem with Samsung phones, I kickstarted the GPS on the phone with

```
HomeScreen.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        }
    });
```

And then called the `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` OR the new `locationClient.getLastLocation` api.

1. First, just add the above lines over your getLastKnownLocation. Things should magically start workings
2. Migrate to LocationClient when you have more time and test again. Use the magic above to get it working if it fails.

Comment: Do I have to import any extra libraries since I'm working with API 10?

Comment: No, you wont need to include any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes device does not receive any location updates and GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER returns null.

Try restarting your device, this trick helped me. My code was perfectly fine but providers were returning null.

Comment: Restarting the device will ultimately solve all problems. But is that something that you really should be doing ? Is that something that you should recommend to millions of your customers ? Windows can afford that due to reputation, Android is stable. If it needs a restart your app is the culprit. Fix it, dont provide workarounds like "restart the device".